# Create circular border around an image with CSS

Tags: css

How can I create a 1px circular border around an image with CSS?

I want to create an icon like one used in some mobile apps, where there is a 1px circular border around an icon image.

Comment: What about using `border-radius` ?

Comment: Jordan already answered, thanks a lot

Comment: If you would have searched, you would have found out by yourself in two minutes - plus learn something else along with it

Comment: I did search and didn't find. Maybe used the wrong keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.circle
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```